# Puppet failed to copy exec catalog

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

Seeing the following error in `Puppet 4`

```
# /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --verbose --no-daemonize --onetime
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for aus-lnaswgp-002.wiley.com
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter unless failed on Exec[sh /home/agile/svncheckout.sh]: 'test -f /home/agile/subversion.done' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path. at /apps/wps/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/subversion.pp:17
```

Code is as follows:

```
      # cat /apps/wps/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/subversion.pp

class subversion {
# A package for subversion install and necessary svn checkouts for user agile

package {'subversion':
    ensure => installed,
}

file {'/home/agile/svncheckout.sh':
  ensure => present,
  group => agile,
  mode => "755",
  source => "puppet://puppet/scripts/svncheckout.sh",
  require => [ Package['subversion'], Class['user_default'] ],
  before => [Class['apache1'], Class['activemq'], Class['luciddb'], Class['sybase']],
}
```

Looks like the script is not able to copy `svncheckout.sh` from `puppet/scripts/svncheckout.sh` . Any suggestion how to resolve the above error ?

Comment: Looks like you asked the same question twice: http://serverfault.com/questions/790988/migrating-puppet-code-to-puppet-4-issue-with-classes

Comment: The failure is because of two reasons.. One is full path required you pointed out  . after that is resolved there was the issue of invalid module directory structure.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you posted has nothing to do with the error being output.

The error is saying that you need to qualify the path of the `unless` command, so `test` becomes `/usr/bin/test` (or wherever the `test` binary is installed on your system).

Use the `which test` command to find the full path to the file, and edit your code accordingly.